# TWebBrowser doesn't display some pages correcty

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer-11, delphi-xe7, chromium-embedded

My problem is that in TWebBrowser (Delphi XE7) there are some pages that doesn't display correctly when in Internet Explorer 11 display's ok. Example of pages that have the issues are https://www.whatismybrowser.com/

I think TWebBrowser is Internet Explorer basis and I don't know because display the page differently that IE11. Is possible solve this?

I search for another alternative components and I found Chromium (DCEF1 and DCEF3 https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3) but only is compatible up to XE5. Do you know another components or a newer version of Chromium compatible with XE 7?

Comment: I have been using Chromium from the link you have supplied and it works nicely on Delphi 10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded webbrowser defaults to Internet Explorer 7, but you can change that on a registry key, declaring the document mode that you want for your application.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation

Comment: I try add my application in the registry key and works fine and TWebBrowser, like IE11, but the solution is not good for me because forces to edit registry key in all client computers that runs the application.

Comment: Then you may want to try Chromium. It has worked very well for me on Delphi 10.1 Berlin, so it's very probable that it will work for you on Delphi XE7. Just install the XE5 package.

Comment: By the way, your application could also check for that Entry on the Registry and if it can't find it, create it (you won't even need elevated rights because you can write those settings on HKEY_CURRENT_USER). It's really easy to do so using the TRegistry class.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I installed Chromium in Delphi XE7 (I solve the problem with FMX library) and the web browser works fine!